# Flutter: disable dropdownbutton option

Tags: flutter

I have this widget:

```
DropdownButton<String>(
        value: rentPeriod,
        items: rentPeriods.map((String value) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: value,
            child: Text(translate("expense.$value")),
          );
        }).toList(),
        onChanged: (value) async {
          setState(() {
            rentPeriod = value;
          });
        },
      ),
```

How can I disable, let's say, the first option of the list?

Comment: You want to disable only one option? Wouldn't be better to hide the option?

Comment: no because I need to display all of them to "force" the user to do some stuff to enable them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i dont think there is any straight forward way of disabling a `DropdownMenuItem`
but you can have a list of the DropdownMenuItems you want to disable and then when you run `setState` you can check if that `DropdownMenuItem` is contained in that list and if it is then do nothing, also check by the DropdownMenuItem text if its contained in that list and if it is then change the color to be greyed out.

Like this

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
    }
    
    class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
      var rentPeriods = <String>['one', 'two'];
      final disabledItems = ['one'];
      var rentPeriod;
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return DropdownButton<String>(
          value: rentPeriod,
          items: rentPeriods.map((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(
                translate("expense.$value"),
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: disabledItems.contains(value) ? Colors.grey : null,
                ),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (value) async {
            if (!disabledItems.contains(value)) {
              setState(() {
                rentPeriod = value;
              });
            }
          },
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: interesting idea. I thought it was a native way to achieve this but this also works

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own disable customization, changing the color and the callback of `onChanged`function in the DropdownButton, like this example:

https://dartpad.dev/587b44d2f1b06e056197fcf705021699?null_safety=true